# Getting stream from Google+ SDK?

Tags: google-plus

Does the current Google+ SDK platform support pulling user stream from Google+ just like facebook/twiter news feed? I did not find anything related in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot fully recreate the Google+ steam using the APIs.

You could get a user's list of friends' public posts if you were using the [plus.login](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes) scope to get access to the [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) method and then used [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) for each person returned in that people list. Then, if you wanted comments, you could use [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list) for each activity. But again that won't recreate the real stream for you because this will only be public data. You'd also likely miss out on some posts like community posts that are public, but wouldn't come into these APIs.

Depending on what your app is trying to do, this might be sufficient if you're only trying to display a feed of your own posts. But if you are trying to create your own Google+ client, this will not work and you would quickly end up running out of quota.

Comment: That means, there is no way to retrieve a "stream" or "feed" like in Facebook/Twitter? Having the same problem in my app :(

Comment: Facebook as far as I know does not provide developers with a way to recreate the timeline, the process would be similar as I outlined for Google+ but with Facebook graph APIs. There are a lot of questions on stack overflow for how to do that with FB and from a quick glance its not a simple API request.

Comment: I was able to code a almost complete users timeline with the graph api, the only thing that doesnt works sometimes: when a user shared a picture from his/her friend i dont connected to - then i get only a "silhouette" picture... but i dont care about that, some methods are some buggy in the facebook graph api :D you only need a access token, without that you get a lot of errors. but ok, you have to code your facebook sdk by your self - the official sdk i was using (java) isnt complete^^

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can pull all activities for a user with activities.list, which will return any posts that user has made and shared as Public.  You can learn more about this at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list.

Comment: In other words, this is the activity FROM the user, not what the user sees on his/her G+ homepage, right?