# android - How to retrieve all the posts in google+?

Tags: android, google-plus

I am newbie to the Google+. I successfully run the sample Google+ app present in the android sdk. I am trying to retrieve all the posts in the user stream. For this i used [google+ api.](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list)

1. But it only returns the posts which is posted as public by the Logged user.
2. Even it not returns the posts by the Logged user as other than public(like "person","circle".. ).
3. It's not returns the posts which are posted by his/her friend in the Logged user wall.

Actually what i need is i want to retrieve all the posts in his/her wall. is it possible? if yes , please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a user's private posts using the API. A stream API does not exist, you [cannot recreate the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074022/getting-stream-from-google-sdk).

Comment: It means we can't retrieve user's private post. How can we retrieve public posts which posted by his/her friend on the logged user wall?